# Printing PHP Array as string, for phalcon php's form->isValid() method

Tags: php, arrays, phalcon

i got a little problem with phalcon php and multidimensional forms.
I'm adding elements to a phalcon form like this:

```
  $display = new Text('language[en-US][display]');
  $display->setLabel($t->_('Display'));
  $display->addValidator(new PresenceOf(array(
    'message' => 'The display field is required'
  )));
  $this->add($display);
```

And in the view this results to:

```
  <input type="text" name="language[en-US][display]" value="some value">
```

which is totally fine and my expected output, but it seems like due to the fact that php automatically converts this syntax (language[en-US][display]) to this array:

```
   array(
     'language' => array(
        'en-US' => array(
           'display' => 'some value'
        )
     )
   )
```

the phalcon php Phalcon\Forms\Form method isValid() cannot assign it to the right form element, when passing it the $_POST data, so my question is, is there a easy way to convert that array to an array like this:

```
  array(
    'language[en-US][display]' => 'some value'
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterating with foreach is enough?

```
$array =  array(
     'language' => array(
        'en-US' => array(
           'display' => 'some value'
        )
     )
   );

$newkey = key($array);
foreach($array[$newkey] as $key=>$val) {
        $newkey .= "[".$key."]";
        foreach ($val as $subkey=>$subval) {
                $newarray[$newkey. "[".$subkey."]"] = $subval;
        }

}

var_dump($newarray);
```